# Align the text in a NSTextField to the top?

Tags: objective-c, swift, cocoa

Here you see the a NSTextField inspected with the view debugger in Xcode. I'd like to have the text top-aligned inside it's bounding box, rather than bottom aligned, so I can align the bottom of the text with some of my other content (images, etc.)

How can such a layout be obtained?

[image]

Comment: Why do you care where the bottom of the text field is if that's not what the baseline is based on? In other words, why is it important to your situation that the text field is taller than its intrinsic height? Perhaps there's a different approach that avoids this problem.

Comment: Because alignment using the topAnchor isn't very useful when there's a arbitrary amount of whitespace between the topAnchor and the actual top of the text.

Comment: I don't understand. A text field would normally be just tall enough to fit the font (ascender plus descender, plus just a little for the border). Why is your text field so much taller than the font? I think it must be something that you did. If that's not what you want, why did you do that? Allow the text field to have its intrinsic height and aligning to the top will be at the top of the (potential) text, although you have to take extra tall characters (like Å) into account. Even if the text field were somehow too tall, just align to the baseline with an offset constant of the ascender.

Comment: No, this is unfortunately standard NSTextField behaviour.

Comment: @ClausJørgensen Have you tried what I suggested?

Answer (score -1):

You need to subclass the `NSTextFieldCell` and override the following method:

```
- (NSRect)drawingRectForBounds:(NSRect)theRect
```

You can use something like `newRect = [super drawingRectForBounds:theRect];` and then try to manipulate `newRect`'s values to achieve what you want.

If needed you can also override these methods:

```
- (void)editWithFrame:(NSRect)aRect inView:(NSView *)controlView editor:(NSText *)textObj delegate:(id)anObject event:(NSEvent *)theEvent

- (void)selectWithFrame:(NSRect)aRect inView:(NSView *)controlView editor:(NSText *)textObj delegate:(id)anObject start:(NSInteger)selStart length:(NSInteger)selLength
```

Comment: @downvoter I've tried this method and it works just fine. However your lack of knowledge on Cocoa or poor programming skills may lead you to find it not useful. So downvote all you want.

Answer (score -1):

You could try the **sizeToFit** method.